# Executing method in MainWindow class

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a WPF application where i use `Frame` to load `Page`'is. On the `Page` i call my custom  contol `<Controls:OrderDataGrid x:Name="cntrlOrderDataGrid" />`.
On this control i have `DataGrid` what is filled with data when i navigate to the `Page` inside the `Frame`. Sometimes the loading takes a while and i need to know when the DataGrid finishes loading, so i have set the `Loaded` event:

```
private void dgOrders_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ }
```

But i cant figure out could i notify the `MainWindow` that the DataGrid has ended loading. When i set the `Loaded` event to the `Frame` then its fired right away without waiting for my custom control with datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to effectively pass the event up.

The `Page` that holds the datagrid needs to add a new event; something like `OrdersLoaded`.  When the datagrid finishes loading fire that event.  The main window can then subscribe to that event, thus telling it when the orders are loaded.

```
public event Action OrdersLoaded;

private void dgOrders_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (OrdersLoaded != null)
        OrdersLoaded();
}
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks. Have been reading about events and delegates so much and trying to get my head around it. Finally got it working. Thanks.